# Increasing speed of circle over time as linear with Box2d

Tags: javascript, box2d, html5, movement

Assume that there is a circle and it can be moved by using keyboard arrows.Is required that increasing speed over time like increasing car speed. For example; max speed is 25 and time to reach max speed shall be 5 sec. Over 5 sec the speed will reach to max speed. Does Box2d handle that situation?.
I tried `setting linear valocity` but it seems to make the circle have constant speed instead of increased speed over time.

Thank You!

Note: I'm using Box2DWeb Javascript port of Box2D.

Comment: Increasing the speed over time is known as **acceleration**. Box2D can handle acceleration.

Comment: Box2d is best when want to run simulations. The more tightly you want to control things the worse it is. At your point I would just do the math yourself. Not to mention Box2D is kinda built around forces and there is nothing linear about how forces effect thigns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Box2D you should just have to apply an Impulse to your object, instead of setting the velocity manually.

```
ApplyImpulse(direction,point)  //Direction = vector
```

For the point, you can always use the center of your Body object by using:

```
Body.GetWorldCenter()
```

By applying small impulses, you will see your object accelerate.  The speed of acceleration will depend on a bunch of variables, such as the force of your impulse, the weight of your object, friction, etc...

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to time the amount of acceleration per frame yourself. There is no built-in function to increase velocity over time to a cap as you described. Extending Jon's answer, you probably end with up some code like this (adapted from http://www.iforce2d.net/b2dtut/constant-speed check it out the page, its very similar to what you want to to do):

```
timer = 5.0f; // 5 seconds    
   update(float delta){ 
        timer -= delta; //timer keeps track of time left
        b2Vec2 vel = body->GetLinearVelocity();
        float desiredVel;
        if(timer > 0)
            desiredVel = MIN_VEL + * acceleration * delta; //m/s
        float velChange = desiredVel - vel.x;
        float impulse = body->GetMass() * velChange; //disregard time factor
        body->ApplyLinearImpulse( b2Vec2(impulse,0), body->GetWorldCenter() );
    }
```